# Why No Constant Linking?

Tags: solidity, compiler, constant

Similarly to library linking
https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/using-the-compiler.html?highlight=compiler%20options#library-linking
why is there no constant linking for the compiler?

The only way to specify constants at the time of the deployment is by declaring `immutable` variables that are then set in the constructor. But the problem with this solution is that it will affect the destination address when using `CREATE2`.

What if I do not want the constant variables to affect the contract address?

**E.g.**, in the contract I would like to have:

```
address constant addr;
```

and not specify its value until deployment:

```
const contractFactory = await this.env.ethers.getContractFactory("Example", {
constants: {
    addr: "0x...",
  },
});
```

similarly to how it works with linking external libraries.

Comment: Can you be more specific? Maybe put an example, code, or screenshot. Anything that can help us understand your concern so we are able to help you.

Comment: Added an example.